# Opening a link automatically on page load?

Tags: plugins

Well I am new and beginner !

I installed [auto thickbox plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-thickbox-plus/) for wp. Now all I want to do is automatically open a link in specific page.

Let's suppose I have a page "about us" on which I have a video.

When I click a nice insite popup appears playing the video by thickbox.

All I want to do is automatically open that video when someone click on "about us" after the page load of "about us".

Kindly help me !

Comment: Want to tell you all the thick box work like when i define class in the link like <a href="http://asd.com" class="thickbox">link popup</a> now if i use jquery how will i put class atribute in the link ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript to trigger events upon page load. The example below uses [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Select a link by ID
    $('#specific-link').trigger('click');

    // Select the first link with a certain class
    $('a.thickbox').first().trigger('click');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Want to tell you all the thick box work like when i define class in the link like <a href="http://asd.com" class="thickbox">link popup</a> now if i use jquery how will i put class atribute in the link ?

Comment: @UbaidRehman I updated the code so it the first thickbox link gets clicked.